# How to change active tab color with time trigger . PHP?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change current tab  li in ul with time trigger but not working. its changing current tab but can not active tab change color, any one can help me, any help will be appreciated.

```
 function Quantitative() {       
        $('#Quantitativetab').trigger('click'); 
        var eng = document.getElementById('EnglishLangImageBox');
        var qua = document.getElementById('QuantitativeLangImageBox');


        var engQue = document.getElementById('English');
        var QuaQue = document.getElementById('Quantitative');

        engQue.style.display='none';
        QuaQue.style.display='block';

    }
```

Time trigger is here.

```
<script>
        // Set the date we're counting down to

        var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2070 15:37:25").getTime();
        //var countDownDate = new .getTime();
        //alert(countDownDate);
        // Update the count down every 1 second

        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("ttime_count").innerHTML =  minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is over, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("ttime_count").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }else if( minutes == 30){
                //$('a#Quantitativetab').trigger('click');
                Quantitative();                     
            }else{
                English();
            }
        }, 1000);       

        </script>
```

tabs code is here.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-nostyle" id="tabnavBar11" style=" height:auto ; border-top: thin solid #000000; border: thin solid #000000; ">
                                <li id="tabs1" class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" id="Englishtab" href="#English" onclick ="SeeEnglish()" style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">English Language <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
                                <li id="tabs2"><a data-toggle="pill" id="Quantitativetab" href="#Quantitative" onclick ="SeeQuantitative()" style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">Quantitative Aptitude <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>                                                           
                            </ul>
```

Comment: I believe that this is not a php related question, please remove php tag. And share your css code as well

Comment: i am using bootstrap 3 ul li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this bootstrap build-in method `$().tab` in your javascript (e.g. `Quantitative()` or `English()`), it activates a tab element and content container.

For your case in `function Quantitative()`

```
function Quantitative() {
    //$('#Quantitativetab').trigger('click');   
    var eng = document.getElementById('EnglishLangImageBox');
    var qua = document.getElementById('QuantitativeLangImageBox');


    var engQue = document.getElementById('Englishtab');
    var QuaQue = document.getElementById('Quantitativetab');

    engQue.style.display = 'none';
    QuaQue.style.display = 'block';
    $(QuaQue).tab('show');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Set the date we're counting down to

  var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2070 15:37:25").getTime();
  //var countDownDate = new .getTime();
  //alert(countDownDate);
  // Update the count down every 1 second

  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("ttime_count").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("ttime_count").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    } else if (seconds % 5 > 2) { // Amended by pblyt in order to trigger the change earlier
      //$('a#Quantitativetab').trigger('click');
      Quantitative();
    } else {
      English();
    }
  }, 1000);


  function Quantitative() {
    //$('#Quantitativetab').trigger('click');   
    var eng = document.getElementById('EnglishLangImageBox');
    var qua = document.getElementById('QuantitativeLangImageBox');


    var engQue = document.getElementById('Englishtab');
    var QuaQue = document.getElementById('Quantitativetab');

    engQue.style.display = 'none';
    QuaQue.style.display = 'block';
    $(QuaQue).tab('show');

  }

  function English() {
    //$('#Quantitativetab').trigger('click');   
    var eng = document.getElementById('EnglishLangImageBox');
    var qua = document.getElementById('QuantitativeLangImageBox');


    var engQue = document.getElementById('Englishtab');
    var QuaQue = document.getElementById('Quantitativetab');

    QuaQue.style.display = 'none';
    engQue.style.display = 'block';
    $(engQue).tab('show');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div id="ttime_count"></div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-nostyle" id="tabnavBar11" style=" height:auto ; border-top: thin solid #000000; border: thin solid #000000; ">
    <li id="tabs1" class="active">
      <a data-toggle="pill" id="Englishtab" href="#English" onclick="" style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">English Language </a>
    </li>
    <li id="tabs2" class="">
      <a data-toggle="pill" id="Quantitativetab" href="#Quantitative" onclick="" style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">Quantitative Aptitude </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention your anchor id was not the same as the tab one. I just added a code snippet as well. Happy coding :)